# Populating 2nd table in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, json

I have two tables (Cell Identifier: Call and Cell Identifier: Cell2). I'm passing two arrays of Objects (one for each table) however when I go to do this in my tableView my 2nd table is bringing up the same data as my first table and not the data from the 2nd array. My arrays are set globally as NSMutableArray in my .h file. This is where I think the problem is within the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

   // NSString *currDate = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Current Date"]; //added
   //  NSString *someOtherKey = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Some other key"]; //added


    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label1.text = [arrayDate1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label2.text = [arrayDate2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   // cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", currDate, someOtherKey]; //added

    return cell;



    //This will Load the second table (myTableView2)
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";


    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

    if(!cell2)
    {
        cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    }

    // NSString *currDate = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Current Date"]; //added
    //  NSString *someOtherKey = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Some other key"]; //added


    cell2.textLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell2;
}
```

Comment: when you return the first time the code below is not executed.

Comment: How can I remedy that, because I know moving the first return above the second will give me the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a problem in this function:

The code as written, will simply run until it gets to the first `return cell;` line and never run the code after that, therefore always returning an instance of a `Cell` cell.

In order to use two tables like this, you need to be able to tell them apart.  Usually, you store both of them in a declared property.  For the rest of this answer, I'll assume that you are doing that and that they are called `table1` and `table2`.

Change you code to look like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.table1]) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

       // NSString *currDate = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Current Date"]; //added
       //  NSString *someOtherKey = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Some other key"]; //added


        cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        label1.text = [arrayDate1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        label2.text = [arrayDate2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       // cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", currDate, someOtherKey]; //added

        return cell;
    } else if ([tableView isEqual:self.table2]) {


        //This will Load the second table (myTableView2)
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";


        UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        if(!cell2)
        {
            cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        }

        // NSString *currDate = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Current Date"]; //added
        //  NSString *someOtherKey = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Some other key"]; //added


        cell2.textLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        return cell2;
    }

}

// If you reach this point, we don't recognize the table and return `nil`, then the program will crash.  Handle this however you want.
return nil;
```